# PHP sum array by month

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me to calculate sum of following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [month] => Jan [planned] => 0.00 [actual] => 15102.70 ) [1] => Array ( [month] => Jan [planned] => 0.00 [actual] => 19452.40 ) [2] => Array ( [month] => Feb [planned] => 15629.80 [actual] => 12478.38 ) [3] => Array ( [month] => Feb [planned] => 39150.00 [actual] => 28003.30 ) [4] => Array ( [month] => Feb [planned] => 8940.00 [actual] => 0.00 ) [5] => Array ( [month] => Mar [planned] => 3600.00 [actual] => 0.00 ) [6] => Array ( [month] => Mar [planned] => 15924.48 [actual] => 3196.05 ) [7] => Array ( [month] => Mar [planned] => 22612.50 [actual] => 14322.13 ) [8] => Array ( [month] => Mar [planned] => 26146.00 [actual] => 0.00 ) )
```

I want sum Month wise:

All planned in Jan

All actual in Jan

likewise every month.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next `foreach loop`:

```
$res_pl = [];
$res_act = [];

foreach($data as $record){

    if (!isset($res_pl[$record['month']])) $res_pl[$record['month']] = 0;
    if (!isset($res_act[$record['month']])) $res_act[$record['month']] = 0;

    $res_pl[$record['month']] += $record['planned'];
    $res_act[$record['month']] += $record['actual'];
}

print_r($res_pl);  // all planned collected by month
print_r($res_act); // all actual collected by month
```

If you need a function, which would return to you values of one defined month, then you can use next code:

```
function getPlannedAndActual($data,$month){

    $res_pl = 0;    // default value
    $res_act = 0;   // default value

    foreach($data as $record){
        if (trim($record['month']) === $month){

            $res_pl += $record['planned'];   // sum of planned
            $res_act += $record['actual'];   // sum of actual
        }
    }

    // resultant array structure
    $res = [ $month => [
                       'planned' => $res_pl, 
                       'actual' => $res_act
                       ]
           ];
    return $res;
}

print_r(getPlannedAndActual($array,'Jan'));
```